# Python Property method for protecting private variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to learn python's OOPS concepts and now I'm trying to learn handling private data in python. I got to know that it can be achived using "Property" method , I'm executing below code but it is thowing me error while i'm trying to access the attribute.

```
class Hello(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def __setname(self, name):
        self.__name = name
    def __getname(self):
        return self.__name
    name = property(__setname, __getname)
h = Hello("Saumya")
print h.name
TypeError: __setname() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Can anynody help me , where am I going wrong ?

Thanks,
Saumya

Comment: are you sure that `property` must be where you put it?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. That's absolutely vital in Python.

Comment: your code is fully broken.

Comment: @Sam I've adjusted the indentation to be consistent with the usage shown after the class definition. Please edit further if that's not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@michael

THanks a lot for your hint, below is the correct code :-

```
>>> class Hello(object):
def __init__(self, name):
    self.__name = name

    def __setname(self, name):
    self.__name = name
def __getname(self):
    return self.__name
    name = property(__getname, __setname)



>>> h = Hello("Saumya")
>>> print h.name
Saumya
```

Answer (score 1):

The `property` function takes the getter first, then the setter:

```
name = property(__getname, __setname)
```